# kurento-client npm not working, tried other versions

Tags: npm, kurento, kurento-media-server

Im trying to npm kurento-client, i have even dropped the versions to install using npm but still no luck.

Here is my package.json file:

```
    {
  "name": "fidb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "kurento-one2many-call =====================",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "minimist": "^1.2.8",
    "ws": "^8.13.0"
  }
}
```

Here are the versions:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/kurento-client/v/6.18.0?activeTab=versions
```

Ive tried some but npm still not working with the versions ive tried.

This on windows